# how to skip rendering outside of given area in maplibre gl js custom layer

Tags: webgl, webgl2, maplibre-gl

i am trying to ignore / skip rendering for pixels falls outside of given bounding box (outside of green border box) something like screenshot attached [image]

i tried different following methods from my understating nothing works,

1. in fragment shader unprojecting gl_FragCoord then comparing with south west, north east values returned by maplibregl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat
2. calculating pixels for min/max latitudes using maplibre project then compared with fragment shader gl_FragCoord.xy

i highly appreciate your help

thank you

Sample testing code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Add a custom style layer</title>
    <meta property="og:description" content="Use a custom style layer to render custom WebGL content."/>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@3.6.2/dist/maplibre-gl.css'/>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/maplibre-gl@3.6.2/dist/maplibre-gl.js'></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        html, body, #map {
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    function addBboxDebugLayer(map, bbox) {
        map.addSource('bbox-debug', {
            'type': 'geojson',
            'data': {
                'type': 'Feature',
                'properties': {},
                'geometry': {
                    'type': 'LineString',
                    'coordinates': [
                        [bbox.w, bbox.n],
                        [bbox.e, bbox.n],
                        [bbox.e, bbox.s],
                        [bbox.w, bbox.s],
                        [bbox.w, bbox.n],
                    ]
                }
            }
        });
        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'bbox-debug',
            'type': 'line',
            'source': 'bbox-debug',
            'layout': {
                // 'line-join': 'round',
                // 'line-cap': 'round'
            },
            'paint': {
                'line-color': '#00ff00',
                'line-width': 1
            }
        });
    }

    
    const map = new maplibregl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        zoom: 3,
        center: [53.33, 24.44],
        style: 'https://demotiles.maplibre.org/style.json',
        antialias: true, // create the gl context with MSAA antialiasing, so custom layers are antialiased
        hash: true,
    });

    const MAX_BOUNDS = [
        30, 8, // south west
        80, 39 // north east
    ];

    const boundsMin = maplibregl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat({
        lng: MAX_BOUNDS[0],
        lat: MAX_BOUNDS[1]
    });
    const boundsMax = maplibregl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat({
        lng: MAX_BOUNDS[2],
        lat: MAX_BOUNDS[3]
    });

    // create a custom style layer to implement the WebGL content
    const highlightLayer = {
        id: 'highlight',
        type: 'custom',

        // method called when the layer is added to the map
        // Search for StyleImageInterface in https://maplibre.org/maplibre-gl-js/docs/API/
        onAdd(map, gl) {
            // create GLSL source for vertex shader
            const vertexSource = `#version 300 es
            uniform mat4 u_matrix;

            in vec2 a_pos;

            void main() {
                gl_Position = u_matrix * vec4(a_pos, 0.0, 1.0);
            }`;

            // create GLSL source for fragment shader
            const fragmentSource = `#version 300 es
            precision highp float;

            uniform vec2 u_canvasSize;
            uniform vec2 u_mapCenter;
            uniform vec2 u_mapSize;
            uniform mat4 u_matrix;

            out vec4 fragColor;

            void main() {
                fragColor = vec4(gl_FragCoord.xy / u_canvasSize , 0.0, 1.);
            }`;


            // create a vertex shader
            const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexSource);
            gl.compileShader(vertexShader);

            // create a fragment shader
            const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentSource);
            gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);

            // link the two shaders into a WebGL program
            this.program = gl.createProgram();
            gl.attachShader(this.program, vertexShader);
            gl.attachShader(this.program, fragmentShader);
            gl.linkProgram(this.program);

            this.aPos = gl.getAttribLocation(this.program, 'a_pos');


            // define vertices of the triangle to be rendered in the custom style layer
            const sw = maplibregl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat({
                lng: MAX_BOUNDS[0] - 5,
                lat: MAX_BOUNDS[1] - 5
            });
            const ne = maplibregl.MercatorCoordinate.fromLngLat({
                lng: MAX_BOUNDS[2] + 5,
                lat: MAX_BOUNDS[3] + 5
            });
            //
            // console.log({
            //     sw: sw,
            //     ne: ne
            // });
            // create and initialize a WebGLBuffer to store vertex and color data
            this.buffer = gl.createBuffer();
            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.buffer);
            gl.bufferData(
                gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,
                new Float32Array([
                    //bottom left
                    sw.x,
                    sw.y,
                    // top left
                    sw.x,
                    ne.y,
                    // bottom right
                    ne.x,
                    sw.y,

                    // bottom right
                    ne.x,
                    sw.y,
                    // top right
                    ne.x,
                    ne.y,
                    // top left
                    sw.x,
                    ne.y,
                ]),
                gl.STATIC_DRAW
            );
        },

        // method fired on each animation frame
        render(gl, matrix) {
            const canvasSize = [gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height];

            gl.useProgram(this.program);
            gl.uniformMatrix4fv(
                gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'u_matrix'),
                false,
                matrix
            );

            gl.uniform2fv(
                gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'u_canvasSize'),
                canvasSize
            );


            gl.uniform2fv(
                gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'u_mapCenter'),
                map.getCenter().toArray()
            );

            gl.uniform2fv(
                gl.getUniformLocation(this.program, 'u_mapSize'),
                [20037508.34 * 2, 20037508.34 * 2]
            );

            gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this.buffer);
            gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this.aPos);
            gl.vertexAttribPointer(this.aPos, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
            gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
            gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 6);
        }
    };

    // add the custom style layer to the map
    map.on('load', () => {
        map.addLayer(highlightLayer, 'crimea-fill');
        addBboxDebugLayer(map, {
            w: MAX_BOUNDS[0],
            s: MAX_BOUNDS[1],
            e: MAX_BOUNDS[2],
            n: MAX_BOUNDS[3]
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```